# Printing character percent in a text file

Tags: python

I just wrote a function which prints character percent in a text file. However, I got a problem. My program is counting uppercase characters as a different character and also counting spaces. That's why the result is wrong. How can i fix this?

```
def count_char(text, char):
    count = 0
    for character in text:
        if character == char:
            count += 1
    return count

filename = input("Enter the file name: ")
with open(filename) as file:
    text = file.read()

for char in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
    perc = 100 * count_char(text, char) / len(text)
    print("{0} - {1}%".format(char, round(perc, 2)))
```

Comment: With "also counting spaces" do you mean that you want the percentages to be a percentage of the letters instead of the total length of the text?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try making the text lower case using  `text.lower()` and then to avoid spaces being counted you should split the string into a list using: `text.lower().split()`. This should do:

```
def count_char(text, char):
    count = 0
    for word in text.lower().split():  # this iterates returning every word in the text
        for character in word:   # this iterates returning every character in each word
            if character == char:
                count += 1
    return count

filename = input("Enter the file name: ")
with open(filename) as file:
    text = file.read()

totalChars = sum([len(i) for i in text.lower().split()]

for char in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
    perc = 100 * count_char(text, char) / totalChars
    print("{0} - {1}%".format(char, round(perc, 2)))
```

Notice the change in `perc` definition, `sum([len(i) for i in text.lower().split()]` returns the number of characters in a list of words, `len(text)` also counts spaces.

Comment: Personally I would convert the text to lower on the open statement. But your example should work fine.

Comment: @dawg You are right, thanks! I modified the code, this should work now.

Comment: Not the *most* efficient to run`sum([len(i) for i in text.lower().split()]` for ever letter of the alphabet. Maybe run that before the loop?

Comment: @dawg I didn't realised that, I defined totalChars before the loop now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to count all letters like so:

```
from collections import Counter 
with open(fn) as f:
    c=Counter(c.lower() for line in f for c in line if c.isalpha())
```

Explanation of generator expression:

```
c=Counter(c.lower() for line in f # continued below


    ^                             create a counter
          ^   ^                   each character, make lower case
                         ^        read one line from the file

 # continued
for c in line if c.isalpha())
    ^                            one character from each line of the file
           ^                     iterate over line one character at a time    
                     ^           only add if a a-zA-Z letter
```

Then get the total letter counts:

```
total_letters=float(sum(c.values()))
```

Then the total percent of any letter is `c[letter] / total_letters * 100`

Note that the Counter `c` only has letters -- not spaces. So the calculated percent of each letter is the percent of that letter of all letters.

The advantage here:

1. You are reading the entire file anyway to get the total count of the character in question and the total of all characters. You might as well just count the frequency of all character as you read them;
2. You do not need to read the entire file into memory. That is fine for smaller files but not for larger ones;
3. A Counter will correctly return `0` for letters not in the file;
4. Idiomatic Python.

So your entire program becomes:

```
from collections import Counter 
with open(fn) as f:
    c=Counter(c.lower() for line in f for c in line if c.isalpha())
total_letters=float(sum(c.values()))
for char in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
    print("{} - {:.2%}".format(char, c[char] / total_letters))
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to make the text lower case before counting the char:

```
def count_char(text, char):
    count = 0
    for character in text.lower():
        if character == char:
            count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in `.count` function to count the characters after converting everything to lowercase via `.lower`.  Additionally, your current program doesn't work properly as it doesn't exclude spaces and punctuation when calling the `len` function.

```
import string
filename = input("Enter the file name: ")
with open(filename) as file:
    text = file.read().lower()

chars = {char:text.count(char) for char in string.ascii_lowercase}
allLetters = float(sum(chars.values()))
for char in chars:
    print("{} - {}%".format(char, round(chars[char]/allLetters*100, 2)))
```

Comment: Since you are using `len(text)` that includes spaces in the calculation

Comment: You have `.lower()` twice and need `float` before the division or it will integer division in Python 2...

Comment: @dawg Updated it